# Boolean always evaluating as true

Tags: c++

i'm making a simple program but there is a problem, boolean always evaluate as true, i don't know what happen, did i missing something or what? please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char kar;
cout<<"Masukan Karakter = ";
cin>>kar;

bool vokal = (kar == ('A','I','U','E','O','a','i','u','e','o'));

string keterangan = vokal ? "Huruf Vokal" : "Bukan Vokal";

cout<<keterangan;

return(0);
}
```

Comment: `(..., ...)` in C++ does not mean what you think it does. Read up about the *comma operator*.

Comment: `return` is not a function. `return(0);` --> `return 0;`

Comment: This will only be `true` if the character you entered is `'o'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
('A','I','U','E','O','a','i','u','e','o')
```

does not represent a set or whatever you think it does. 
Everything between those `','` (*commas*) is considered to be an expression. That part of the code evaluates every expression from left to right, and returns the rightmost evaluation.

In your case: expression `'A'` evaluates to `'A'`, `'I'` evaluates to `'I'`, ..., `'e'` evaluates to `'e'` and `'o'` evaluates to `'o'`. After every expression is evaluated, value `'o'` is returned. That's why your `kar` will always be compared with `'o'` and this code would behave the same as yours:

```
bool vokal = (kar == 'o');
```

---

What you actually need to do is compare `kar` with every one of those characters, seperately (using the OR (`'||'`) operator in your case):

```
bool vokal = (kar == 'A' || kar == 'I' || kar == 'U' || kar == 'E' || kar == 'O' 
           || kar == 'a' || kar == 'i' || kar == 'u' || kar == 'e' || kar =='o');
```